# Eclipse IDE Auto complete bug skipping line and moving cursor to middle of the next line

Tags: eclipse

How do you fix Eclipse IDE to stop skipping a line and jumping into the middle of the next line every time you use ctrl space and enter to autocomplete?

Every time I hit enter to choose an autocomplete option the cursor leaves the line and ends up one tab amount of space into the next line even if that means its in the middle of a line of existing code! Another weird thing is that a light green line appease beside it!

Comment: which version of eclipse are you using

Comment: @guleryuz I'm running Eclipse Mars 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little to late to answer this however if someone is facing the same problem, the solution is below

`Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist`

In the `Insertion` tab, choose `Completion inserts` instead of `Completion Overwrites`.

Comment: Thank you for this, it boggles the mind this is standard behavior in eclipse. But so do a lot of things with it...